# How to print the string value of a choices field

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have an integer field that provides 3 choices for a blog post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_DRAFT = 0
    STATUS_PUBLISHED = 1
    STATUS_DELETED = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_DRAFT, 'draft'),
        (STATUS_PUBLISHED, 'published'),
        (STATUS_DELETED, 'deleted'),
    )

    status = IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=STATUS_DRAFT)
```

When I render this in a template with `{{ blog.status }}` it prints the integer value (`0, 1, 2`). How can I call it to print the string value (`draft, published, deleted`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**`get_fieldname_display`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display):

> For every field that has `choices` set, the object will have a `get_FOO_display()` method, where `FOO` is the name of the field. This method returns the "human-readable" value of the field.

In this case, you thus can implement it with:

```
{{ blog.get_status_display }}
```